# Button counter Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to ask you about correction of my code.
I wanted to create a button after clicking on the button text would change every second (asynchronously).
Is this code correct or should I do it differently?

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public List<int> figures = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(var figure in figures)
        {
            await TimeSleeper(figure);
        }

    }
    public async Task TimeSleeper(int figure)
    {
        button1.Text = figure.ToString();
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
        button1.Refresh();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfection is in the eye of the beholder I suppose. But this is not really a pretty way of doing it :P

Instead of defining the list "figures" you can use

```
IEnumerable.Range(1, 10)
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.8

TL:DR, it defines a range starting from the first param, ending in the last param.

Instead of doing

```
Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
```

You could simplify it by doing

```
Task.Delay(1000)
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.8

Other than that... it works right? And it is readable, that is what is important.